# Bookmarks disappeared in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

I can't find my bookmarks anymore. I post as a screenshot as proof. Are they somewhere else now.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bookmarks are now at its own "Saves" tab, since you can now bookmark not only questions, but also answers.

[image]

Reference: [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/168244)